# How to draw vertical lines over two diagrams?

Tags: line, gnuplot

Since SF seems to have further problems it is kind of difficult to find answers to this question. I already know how to plot 2 diagrams with (set) multiplot. But how can I draw some vertical lines going over both diagrams. eg.

```
set parametric
set trange [a:b]
plot 16,t
```

I have no clue how to do this over two plots.
The plot should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/90Uue.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, I use `set arrow ... nohead` to draw vertical lines. In order to plot them over two plots, I would use `screen` coordinates for the y-value:

```
set multiplot layout 2,1
set xrange [0:300]
set arrow 1 from first 16,screen 0.05 to first 16, screen 0.95 nohead lc rgb 'red' lw 2
set arrow 2 from first 256,screen 0.05 to first 256, screen 0.95 nohead lc rgb 'red' lw 2

plot x
unset arrow

plot 2*x
unset multiplot
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet that illustrates how to do it (though it needs some tuning in alignment).

```
set multiplot

# plot 1
set origin 0,0
set size  1,.5
set xrange [0:2*pi]
set yrange [-1.1:1.1]
plot sin(x)

# plot 2
set origin 0,.5
set size 1,.5
plot cos(x)

# line
set origin 0,0
set size 1,1
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset xlabel
unset ylabel
unset border
set parametric
plot 1,t

unset  multiplot
```